# How to insert a point in a txt file?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I would like to insert a dot"..." in a cvs file with the help of vba after I have deleted its contents. 
In fact, it would solve the problem of "insufficient memory"

```
 Sub StartExtract()      
' Load the CSV file
 OpenCSVFile

Sheets("temp").Select
Sheets("NS_Aug_310_330").Select
Columns("A:F").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\p100789\Documents\SAP\SAP 
GUI\text.txt"
Cells.ClearContents
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add whatever you like to cell `A1` of that "workbook" before saving and it should work. It may be a bit easier to work with the csv if you assign the "Workbook" to a variable. Then you can just add your ... to `Range("A1")`

```
Dim wb as workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\p100789\Documents\SAP\SAP GUI\text.txt")
wb.Sheets(1).Cells.ClearContents
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "..."
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: In reality I just want to fill in the cvs file also not the macro plant when there is no data inside.Thank you for ur answer!

Comment: "I just want to fill in the cvs file also not the macro plant when there is no data inside" I don't understand what this means. Is it that you only want to put `...` when the text.txt file is empty? If that's the case you could test after opening. `If wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "" Then` do the next two lines.

Comment: This is not what I want, I would like to put a point directly in my CVS file but thank you for your answer